# How to modify the admin template in django

Tags: python, django

i use the django's default admin for the admin site, and i create a app named "project"
[image]

Then in the project change form, i want to show and dynamic image, i plan to draw some charts using the google API, so i must put change the html form to add a  in the html file as below:

[image]

So my question is that how can i modify the django's default templates for this page, i can not find the form in templates/ folder, is this page named "change_form"? "change_list"? or some other names. If so ,how do i only change the form for app "Project" since maybe i will create some other apps in the same level with "project"

Answer (score 1):

You need a place for static files which is valid.

Then place an admin directory inside that static files directory.

Then add your addname as a directory like this:

```
Root
  yourapp
     static
        admin
           yourapp
               file_to_overwrite
```

Find your Django files. Then go to:
**contrib/admin/templates/admin**

On OSX this would be:

**/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin**

Copy the file you want to overwrite to yourapp directory like above.

**EDIT:**

If you want to change a single form for a single app:

For example:

```
Root
  yourapp
     static
        admin
           yourapp
               modelname
                   change_form.html
```

Only the model "modelname" will be affected by this html-file.

Comment: i have made a mistake, the "project" is only a model of my app "ticket", i want to change "project"'s form

Comment: these files change as django upgrades so please see answer below for a better approach

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this as the docs suggests is go with @Rickard Zachrisson answer but instead of copying it use the "extends" block and import super.

this should be a better approach since you are not directly overriding the admin templates but instead inheriting them.

This is how the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/javascript/) suggests to do it when inserting JS for example:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block admin_change_form_document_ready %}
{{ block.super }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app/formset_handlers.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```